# Inverting the order of the gcc output

Tags: bash, gcc

I'd like to reverse the order of the errors founded by gcc in my programs. Why? to read the first error at last line and avoid to scroll until the first line.

I searched on gcc, cat, tail and head manuals for an command like --reverse without results. So, I'd like to a program who print the standard input in inverse order. Anyone knows something like that?

Comment: have you tried `tac` ? Something like this should work : `gcc main.c 2>&1 | tac` (note that `2>&1` is needed because `gcc` displays its error messages to stderr) **EDIT** : this will display the exact reverse of the message, and will not be consistent with the bloc structure of `gcc`. Could you expand your question if this is not the behaviour you are looking for ?

Comment: @Aserre yes, something like that is what I'm looking for, it does not preserve the structure, but its ok to debug a little big faster. But now, it does not show colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following script :

```
unbuffer gcc main.c 2>&1 | tac
```

Explanation :

- `unbuffer` : disables buffering for the pipe, and allows gcc to retain its color scheme through the execution.
- `gcc main.c 2>&1` :

  - Your `gcc` command can be as long as you need and contain all the falgs you usually use (it is not limited to just 1 file. Just keep the redirection as the last parameter)
  - `2>&1` : I/O redirection. `stderr` is redirected to `stdout`
- `tac` : same command as `cat`, but prints the concatenated result in reverse.

---

If you don't have it installed on your machine, `unbuffer` is in the package `expect-dev` on Debian based distros, and `tac` is part of `coreutils`.

Comment: Just what im looking for, thank you, @Aserre. In Fedora the package is called expect-devel

Comment: Unfortunately, this trick doesn't work on `clang`.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick Are you using `clang` through an alias by any chance ? If so, I encourage you to have a read at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249737/49321)

Comment: @Aserre No, I am not using an alias. I mean, on `clang-11`, I get `2 errors generated.`
`          ^`
`int main() {`
`test.c:3:12: note: to match this '{'`
 `^`
`}`, etc.

Comment: @Aserre In other words, I get error messages with lines out of order and messed up colors on `clang-11`.