# g++/clang++ Invert compilation error order

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

g++ and clang++ report compilation errors with the first erroneous line encountered at the top of their output. That is, the first line clang/g++ print on a compilation error are the one you usually care about. As I'm sure we have all experienced, you have to scroll up (often a lot) to see what the nasty error is. Is there any compilation flag (in clang++ or in g++) that presents compilation errors in reverse order?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51287431/is-it-possible-to-invert-the-order-errors-are-displayed) which asked the same thing I'm asking, but about GHC and thought about how much of a useful option this would be for C++ projects. I've never heard of this for clang++ or g++, and I couldn't find anything online nor on their man pages.

Comment: use an IDE/smart editor/less. Or `-fmax-errors`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41223061/9593596

Comment: You can use `-Wfatal-errors` to have the compiler stop after the first error.